# Angle and distance from reference point to orthogonal basis vectors

Tags: trigonometry, orthogonality

Say I have some arbitrary point (top-left corner) in production plant and the location of every piece of machinery is detailed in relation to this fixed point given distance and angle.

I would like to know a function, `f(angle, distance)` that would return (x,y) coordinates of any piece of machinery where X and Y are orthogonal dimensions. In other words, I would like to know the distance along the X dimension and distance along the Y dimension that a given piece of machinery is offset from the reference point.

Is this as simple as below function?

```
def f(angle, distance):
   x = distance * cos(angle)
   y = distance * sin(angle)
   return (x,y)
```

Comment: I don't know why I overthought this; of course this is right https://www.construct.net/en/forum/construct-2/how-do-i-18/calculate-position-xy-using-78314

Comment: It depends on how you define the angle relative to your coordinate axes. You say your origin is the "top-left corner". If that means the positive $x$-axis is pointing right, and the  positive $y$-axis is pointing down, then the angle has to be to the positive $x$-axis, and is measured clockwise for this function to work. In standard mathematical practice, the positive $y$-axis points up, and angles to the $x$-axis are measured counter-clockwise. The two reversals of direction cancel each other, so the same formulae work there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is perfect for the use case.

```
def f(angle, distance):
   x = distance * cos(angle)
   y = distance * sin(angle)
   return (x,y)
```